# Docker secure the image and container which contains the binaries and source code

Tags: docker, security, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is there any way I can protect my binaries inside the image and container secure by not accessing by user?

Comment: No. If the user has control of the host machine, they will be able to access your binaries. You can make it hard by obfuscating your code and/or encrypting it. But in the end it needs to be decrypted to run and the user will be able to access it.

Comment: ...and if they can run any `docker` command at all, they can trivially get root access on the host.  You can't prevent a user from `docker run`ning a shell (assuming your image contains one), `docker export`ing a container to a tar file, or manually poking around in `/var/lib/docker` to find the image content.

Answer (score 0):

You have goods practices for protect your image content :

1. Start docker with specific user (not admin) on the machine
2. Push the image to a private repo
3. Don't put any sensitive information under the image. Use Environment
   variables for example for any secret key or any identification.
   Populate the Environment viriables only when you run the image (with
   docker-compose for example)

I hope it will help you a little and it answers to your question.